# Highlight the row in the listview (eg change the background color) for a while

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am looking for some solution to highlight some row in the listview. In my custom `Adapter` in method `getView()` I am making some data comparison and if it gives me true I want to highlight that row but just only for some small period of time. It could be changing the background color for a while and geting back to normal state. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a `Handler` linked to the UI thread and use `postDelayed` to continuously update the highlight for a short period of time. The delay duration will effectively be the frame rate of the highlight color decay.